# View does not show up in layers dialog of QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I create a `View` with a long `CTE`

`CREATE VIEW foo AS WITH joined_socio AS (...`

As far as I know, I should be able to visualize `Views` in `QGIS`.
However, when I go into `QGIS -> Layer -> Add Layer -> PostGIS`, connect to the database that holds the `View`, I only see the `Tables`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Database Manager (from the Menubar under Database)as opposed to the Add Layers, you can add the tables that way also.
Hope that Helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the `View` was not spatial. Apparently, QGIS has trouble displaying non-spatial-Views in the `Add Layer Dialogue`.

Comment: You can enable seeing non-spatial relations in the connection config.